Why does KDE's Discover and Apper show "orphan-sysvinit-scripts" should be updated but not apt-get upgrade --- should it be installed?
After upgrading to Debain12 with KDE, the package managers Apper and Discover show that a package "orphan-sysvinit-scripts" should be updated.
But I don't have that package installed so why would it need to be updated?
In addition, sudo apt-get upgrade does not show the package should be installed (it only shows The following packages have been kept back: sysv-rc-conf which likely causes some users to install it manually accidentally removing hundreds of essential packages that it wants to remove).
It wants to install version 0.14 from +auto:debian-stable-main. I thought it only uses apt-get and should only display packages that the apt-get upgrade command also shows. It also shows no file-size for the package (nothing in the "Size" column of Apper).
Bug report is here.

It's gone after removing sudo apt-get remove sysv-rc-conf which is not needed if you're not using sysvinit. See the linked question.
